# How to mass update product from array of products with unique data per product?

Tags: magento2, product

I'm looking for a better way to mass update product from an array of products with different data per product.

After some google searches I tested to use a function like this but I'm sure this can be done better.

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface[] $products
 */
public function updateProductArray($products)
{
    /** @var $product \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface */
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        try {
            $this->productRepository->save($product);
        }
        catch (\Exception $e){
            //LOG SOMETHONG
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to speed this up?

Answer (score 0):

The following method for mass updating product info is contained in the catalog module - Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action. I think this will be much faster.

```
public function updateAttributes($productIds, $attrData, $storeId)
{
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
        'catalog_product_attribute_update_before',
        ['attributes_data' => &$attrData, 'product_ids' => &$productIds, 'store_id' => &$storeId]
    );

    $this->_getResource()->updateAttributes($productIds, $attrData, $storeId);
    $this->setData(
        ['product_ids' => array_unique($productIds), 'attributes_data' => $attrData, 'store_id' => $storeId]
    );

    if ($this->_hasIndexableAttributes($attrData)) {
        $this->_productEavIndexerProcessor->reindexList(array_unique($productIds));
    }

    $categoryIndexer = $this->indexerRegistry->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Category::INDEXER_ID);
    if (!$categoryIndexer->isScheduled()) {
        $categoryIndexer->reindexList(array_unique($productIds));
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I will use this suggestion to other things. In my case i have unique values for each product i want to update.  But as i understand it this updates all products in $productIds with the same value for attrData. (I'll changed the question to clarify this)

Answer (score 0):

You can use product import with a custom source to speed up the process. See performance tool fixtures as example

Comment: is this a good place to start looking? vendor/mag‌​ento/magento2-base/s‌​etup/src/Magento/Set‌​up/Fixtures/SimplePr‌​oductsFixture.php